# Apache Server Side Includes Won't Expand Variables in Regular Expressions

Tags: apache, apache2

I am trying to use an SSI variable in an SSI regular expression like the 3rd line ( I will paste the full test code further down)

```
<!--#set var="referrer" value="https://edcint.co.nz/test1.shtml " -->
<!--#set var="host" value="edcint.co.nz" -->
<!--#if expr="$referrer = /$host/" -->
```

But it does not work on my hosting provider. This works on my home installation of apache.

My test URL should not have any red text returned if it is working properly.

In the code below I am trying to see if the content of the "host" variable in included in the content of the "referrer" variable.

The full page source is:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!--#set var="referrer" value="https://edcint.co.nz/test1.shtml " -->
<!--#set var="host" value="edcint.co.nz" -->

<hr>
Test using Variable<br>
<!--#if expr="$referrer = /$host/" -->
   <!--#echo var="referrer" --> includes <!--#echo var="host" -->
<!--#else -->
   <!--#echo var="referrer" --> <span style="color: red;">DOES NOT INCLUDE</span> <!--#echo var="host" -->
<!--#endif -->

<hr>
Test using Hardcoding<br>
<!--#if expr="$referrer = /edcint.co.nz/" -->
   <!--#echo var="referrer" --> includes <!--#echo var="host" -->
<!--#else -->
   <!--#echo var="referrer" --> DOES NOT INCLUDE <!--#echo var="host" -->
<!--#endif -->

<hr>


</body>
</html>
```

This is running on apache httpd v2.4.5x

Maybe there is another way to achieve what I am trying to do. Here is the background:

I have modified by original code here for posting but what I really want to do is only allow pages on my site to load if they are accessed either directly or by clicking a link on my site. I am trying to block pages being referenced from any other site. I had this working just fine and then I changed hosting providers and it stopped working - hence this post

Comment: I have just found out that the provider is running Litespeed. I assume that this is the problem - this functionality is outside of the capability of Litespeed. I still wonder if there is configuration that can be made to make it work.

Comment: I've removed the link to your website in both this question and your previous question. Website troubleshooting and questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here. Questions need to be self-contained so that users are not required to visit your site.

Comment: Thanks @max. I thought it would still be ok since I posted the complete code as well. I have used this same approach on other stackexchange sites as well and it has been ok

Comment: No probs! Thanks for posting the complete code. It's quite likely that other Stack Exchange sites have different policies than ours, and that's totally fine.

Comment: "This is running on apache httpd v2.4.5x" / "I have just found out that the provider is running Litespeed." - Just curious what made you think it was "Apache v2.4.5x" initially? Many who are on LiteSpeed _assume_ they are using Apache, but unsure of the version.

Comment: "what I really want to do is only allow pages on my site to load if they are accessed either directly or by clicking a link on my site" - You can do this (arguably more easily) using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`, which is supported by both Apache and LiteSpeed. Is this an option for you?